# Как попарно сравнить все элементы двумерного массива в Java?

Tags: java, массивы, двумерный-массив

Есть двумерный массив: 4 строки и 3 столбца. Мне необходимо каждый элемент сравнить с каждым. Есть идея делать "в лоб" через 4 цикла. Может знаете как сделать проще?

Этот код не отрабатывает корректно:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {    
        for (int k = j + 1; k < 3; k++) {
            //arr[i][j]==arr[i][k]...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем 4 цикла? Массив двумерный, значит, всего 2 цикла.

Comment: так мне же надо взять, например, элемент [0][0] и сравнить с абсолютно каждым элементом. Предложи как это сделать

Comment: Извиняюсь, что быканул

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментарии @Byb указал верно, достаточно двух циклов, так как сравнивается пара элементов, причём во вложенном цикле достаточно начинать итерацию со "следующего" элемента после текущего.  Итерация будет выполняться до `M * N`, где `M` -- число строк, `N` -- число столбцов, как в обычном линейном массиве, но каждый индекс надо будет сконвертировать в пару `строка-столбец` при помощи операций деления и нахождения остатка:

```java
int M = 4, N = 3;
int[][] arr = new int[M][N];

for (int i = 0, mn = M * N; i < mn; i++) {
    // пара индексов для первого элемента в сравнении
    int r1 = i / N;
    int c1 = i % N;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < mn; j++) {
        // пара индексов для второго элемента в сравнении
        int r2 = j / N;
        int c2 = j % N;

        if (arr[r1][c1] != arr[r2][c2]) {
            // сделать что-то для разных элементов
        } else {
            // сделать что-то для одинаковых элементов
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы гений! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: нажал, у меня просто инет не очень сервер то регает нажатия, то нет\